# Angular 2 - get barcode scanner data without using HTML input/textarea

Tags: javascript, html, angular, barcode

I'm creating web application which uses barcode scaner (in my case Motorola TC55).

My goal is to scan product EAN without using HTML input/textarea. Why? Because I want to prevent pop up keyboard on mobile devices. This field should be usable on desktops too (without connected scanner - to input data from keyboard).

What I've tried:

1. Set `readonly`/disabled attribute on input - mobile keyboard is hidden, but I can't set focus on this input.
2. Create `div` with `contenteditable` directive - keyboard is visible.
3. And finally (the most sofisticated so far) - create `div` with `onClick` event. After click in `div` I'm starting listening to `keypress` and saving everything until `Enter` key is pressed. It works fine on desktop. On mobile keyboard is hidden but `keypress` event is triggered only on end of scanning (`Enter` key).

Any other sugestions?

Answer (score 1):

*Disclaimer: I work for Zebra Technologies*

Because you're working on a [Motorola (now Zebra Technologies) TC55](https://www.zebra.com/TC55), you have available different options.

The easiest is to use something like [Zebra's Enterprise Browser](https://www.zebra.com/enterprisebrowser), it requires a license, but it includes some additional APIs that allows to control the additional HW of the device. In particular you've available a [Barcode API](http://techdocs.zebra.com/enterprise-browser/1-7/api/barcode/) that allow you to take full control of the integrated barcode scanner.

If you prefer to use something that requires a bit more hand-holding, you can take a look at [this blog post that explain how to bridge between DataWedge (the application that on the Zebra Android devices is sending the barcode data as characters) and the Chrome Android Browser using WebSockets](http://www.darryncampbell.co.uk/2017/06/11/datawedge-to-websockets-bridge/).

If you have a support contract for your TC55 you can update your device to the latest security updates and fixes. You can find more information on [Zebra's Support Website](https://www.zebra.com/us/en/support-downloads/mobile-computers/handheld/tc55.html).

Comment: I have a CT60 from Honeywell and they offer a BarcodeReader API, but I don't want to pay perpetually to use it. Why pay a company to use a product that costs thousands.